# how to add/subtract 2 days in the target day in python?

Tags: python, date

I have a problem in adding or subtracting 2 days to the target day...
here is my code :

```
import datetime

target_date = datetime.date(2011,2,7)
```

thanks

Comment: what's the problem (question)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
import datetime
target_date = datetime.date(2011,2,7)

delta = datetime.timedelta(days=2)
new_date = target_date - delta

print new_date # 2011-02-05
```